# How to prevent tinymce from stripping out style attribute in chrome?

Tags: tinymce, browser

I have to prevent tinymce from stripping out style attribute.I have defined **extended_valid_elements** for that and It's working in firefox but not in chrome.

I have defined like that :

```
'extended_valid_elements' => "@[id|class|title|style|data-options|data*],a[name|href|target|title],#p,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src|height|width],-b,-i,-u,-span[data-mce-type],hr",
'inline_styles' => true,
'verify_html' => false,
```

What can i do ? 
Thanks For any Help.